# Not sure how to solve Bayesian parameter learning problem

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian

I could use some help solving a problem about a [Dirichlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Probability_density_function) prior.

We have a multinomial distribution over an alphabet of 27 symbols parameterized by $\mathbf{\theta}=(\theta_1, ..., \theta_{27})$. We have collected a dataset $D = \{x[1],\ldots,x[2000]\}$ consisting of $2000$ symbols, among which "e" appears $260$ times.  We use a Dirichlet prior over $\theta$ with parameters $\mathbf{\alpha}= (\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_{27})$,  where each $\alpha_i = 10$. 
 What is the predictive probability that letter "e" occurs with this prior? (i.e., what is $P(X[2001] = $ "$e$"$ \mid D)$?)

So my understanding is that we are to find  $P(X_{2001} | X_1, X_2, ... X_{2000})$. By the given information, and since this is a Bayesian probability question, it appears that we must  apply the chain rule of conditional probability here. If we also observe the conditional independence of $X_1, X_2, ... X_{2001}$ given $\theta$, we have

$$P(X_{2001} | X_1, ... X_{2000}, \theta)P(\theta|X_1, X_{2000})= P(X_{2001}  |\theta)P(\theta|X_1, X_{2000})$$

and from law of total probability,
$$ =\int_{\theta} P(X_{2001} |\theta)P(\theta|X_1, ... X_{2000}) \mathrm d\theta  $$

Now to solve the integral, I am left with some questions. What is $P(X_{2001}|\theta)$?  Is this simply $\theta$? Can this probability be derived from the multinomial of $X$ given $\alpha$?

How do we find the posterior $P(\theta|X_1, ... X_{2000})$? I was thinking that since the Dirichlet (Beta) is a conjugate prior to the multinomial (binomial), that this posterior might be

$$P(\theta|X_1, ... X_{2000}) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_5+  260 + \sum_{i=1}^{26} \alpha_i + \frac{2000-260}{26})}{\Gamma(\alpha_5 + 260)\Pi_{i=1}^{26}\Gamma(\alpha_i + \frac{2000-260}{26})} \theta_{5}^{10+260-1}\Pi_{i=1}^{26}\theta_{i}^{1000/13 - 1}$$

Where the subscript $5$ denotes the index for "e" in the parameter vectors. $\alpha_i$ is the value of the $i$th value in the vector $\alpha$ after the $2000$ observations (inclusive of the starting prior parameter values of $\alpha_i=10$). Next, substituting the given information that "e" was observed $260$ of the $2000$ times gives me

$$P(\theta|X_1, ... X_{2000}) = \frac{\Gamma(260)\Gamma(1740)}{\Gamma(260)\Pi_{i=1}^{26}\Gamma(\alpha_i))} \theta_{5}^{260}\Pi_{i=1}^{1740}\theta_{i}^{\alpha_i}$$

I am very unsure of my work so far, and I am not sure how to finish solving this. The last expression is in terms of the vector $\theta$, and I would not know how to integrate such an expression.

I was wondering if it is possible to simplify this problem by modeling the distribution over $\mathbf{\theta}$ as a binomial distribution instead of a Dirichlet. It appears that is really only a binary event here: either "e" is observed or some other symbol was observed.

Comment: Technically, you only need a Beta distribution here, since you only talk about one of the characters. So you'll only be able to estimate one parameter with this partial information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that you start from the Dirichlet distribution as a prior, i.e.

$$p(\theta)=\frac{\Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^{27} \alpha_i)}{\Pi_{i=1}^{27}\Gamma(\alpha_i)} \Pi_{i=1}^{27}\theta_i^{\alpha_i}$$

Then, you obtain some data which have a certain probability under the hypothesis that the $\alpha_i$ have certain values.

$$P(X_1,\ldots,X_{2000}|\theta)={2000 \choose {N_1,\ldots,N_{27}}} \Pi_{i=1}^{27}{\theta_i}^{N_i}$$

In which an $N_i=\sum_k I(X_k=i)$ or in words $N_i$ counts how many times the $i$th symbol appears. From this you now compute the posterior as

$$P(\theta|X_1,\ldots,X_{2000})=\frac{P(X_1,\ldots,X_{2000}|\theta)p(\theta)}{\int P(X_1,\ldots,X_{2000}|\theta)p(\theta) d\theta}$$

However, you only have partial information about the letter "e". Let's say that letter "e" is the 5th symbol, then the probability of it appearing 260 times under your hypothesis is

$$P(N_5=260|\theta)={2000 \choose 260} {\theta_5}^{260}(1-\theta_5)^{2000-260}$$

and applying the Bayesian updating rule we should write

$$P(\theta|N_5=260)=\frac{P(N_5=260|\theta)p(\theta)}{\int P(N_5=260|\theta)p(\theta) d\theta}$$

Working out the integral

$$\int P(N_5=260|\theta)p(\theta) d\theta = {2000 \choose 260} \frac{\Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^{27} \alpha_i)}{\Pi_{i=1}^{27}\Gamma(\alpha_i)} \int {\theta_5}^{260}(1-\theta_5)^{2000-260}  \prod_{i=1}^{27}\theta_i^{\alpha_i} \Pi_{i=1}^{27}d\theta_i$$

The factor in front is irrelevant since it will cancel with the one from the numerator in our end formula, let's concentrate on

$$\int {\theta_5}^{260}(1-\theta_5)^{2000-260}  \prod_{i=1}^{27}\theta_i^{\alpha_i} \Pi_{i=1}^{27}d\theta_i = \int {\theta_5}^{\alpha_5+260}(\sum_{i\neq 5}\theta_i)^{2000-260}  \prod_{i\neq 5}\theta_i^{\alpha_i} \Pi_{i=1}^{27}d\theta_i$$

We work out the $(\sum_{i\neq 5}\theta_i)^{2000-260}$ with the multinomial theorem

$$(\sum_{i\neq 5}\theta_i)^{2000-260}=\sum_{k_i}{{2000-260} \choose {k_1,\ldots,\hat{k}_5\ldots,k_{27}}}\prod_{i\neq 5}\theta_i^{k_i}$$

which gives us for the integral

$$\int {\theta_5}^{\alpha_5+260}(\sum_{i\neq 5}\theta_i)^{2000-260}  \prod_{i\neq 5}\theta_i^{\alpha_i} \Pi_{i=1}^{27}d\theta_i = \sum_{k_i}{{2000-260} \choose {k_1,\ldots,\hat{k}_5\ldots,k_{27}}}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_5+260)\prod_{i\neq 5}\Gamma(\alpha_i+k_i)}{\Gamma(\sum_i \alpha_i + 2000)}$$

Comment: Thanks, I am still trying to make sure I understand the problem. I do not quite follow how you did the integral just before "We work out the $(\sum_{i \ne 5} \theta_i)$", but maybe there is a theorem in Calculus I need to review.

Comment: I will probably ask another question on how to solve the modified problem where we must find the probability of more than one possible symbol, where it may not be possible to use a binomial and beta distribution, and we would be forced to use the Dirichlet and Multinomial distributions

Comment: I do not integrate in that step, I just rewrite $1-\theta_5=\sum_{i \ne 5} \theta_i$.